# How to run an event in C# when a Particular value is inserted in sql server table..?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a live application logging some values from a device @ the rate of one insertion per second.

Now my problem is i want to get notified in my UI when value inserted in table goes out of a range...

I don't Know how to implement this... 
Please help with which technique to use... is it trigger or CLR trigger or any other way....??

Comment: Show code. State what you tried.

Comment: If you are looking for something specific, please ask specific question

Comment: which value ? what exactly you mean by out of range ?

Comment: Maybe you can use the observer pattern for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a timer to verify the newly inserted values, or, if you want to use a  trigger, print some information and use `SqlConnection.InfoMessage` event. In your event handler query the table for new values. Be aware that the second option would require a permanently opened connection which may be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SQL server notification service.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966501.aspx